# Kernel panics in FreeBSD 9.1 virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd, debug, kernel-panic, dump

I'm regularly encountering a kernel panic on my FreeBSD 9 laptop. I have installed virtualbox host and trying to run CentOS as guest. When perform "yum repolist" guest crash's my freebsd host.

Here are the kernel dump -> http://pastebin.com/RPgyyWk1

Comment: it might be worth to report the backtrace to the freebsd-net@freebsd.org mailinglist.